# fetch multiple rows from mysql with one query and use them in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Hi there i got stuck on this code and i don't seem to find a solution to it.
I have this now...
[pdf download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHIAL.png)

and i want to display this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ1ay.png)

all the PDFs are in a table and one product have 2-3 PDFs
here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgsYS.png)

and the table looks like this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEKsX.png)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Did you even bother with the question? You didn't even fill out the "enter image description here"...

Comment: Provide code instead of Image for a get better help for this question...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not placing the code:
here is the code i speak and the images is for a visual aspect of what i want the code to do...

```
<?php 
$data_sheet = false;
$datasheet_query = $db->Execute("SELECT TECHLINK_ID, TECHLINK_INCODE, TECHLINK_URLID, TECHLINK_products_id, TECH_URL, TECH_TITLE
                                FROM FTECHLINK
                                LEFT JOIN FTECHSHEET_URL ON TECH_ID = TECHLINK_URLID
                                WHERE TECHLINK_products_id = ".(int)$_GET['products_id']."");
if (!$datasheet_query->EOF){
    $data_sheet = true;
    $pdf_title = $datasheet_query->fields['TECH_TITLE'];
    $pdf_file = $datasheet_query->fields['TECH_URL'];
    $pdf_path = "acrobat/".$pdf_file;
    $image_name = str_ireplace('.pdf','.jpg',$pdf_file);
    $image_path = "acrobat/".$image_name;
    $tech_image = '<div class="download_image_container"><a href="' . $pdf_path . '"target="_blank">' . zen_image($image_path, $products_name, "173", "245", 'class="box_image_pdf"') . '</a></div>';
    $tech_title = '<div class="download_title_container"><a class="document_title"href="' . $pdf_path . '"target="_blank">' . $pdf_title . '</a></div>';
}
?>


     <?php if ($data_sheet == true) { ?>
        <div id="datasheet" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="product-tab">
            <?php 
                echo $tech_image;
                echo $tech_title;
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```